# Modifying an object returned by a suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-native

I've recently started Kotlin and now am beating with some basic stuff as it seems. Imagine I have a class which is used to access database and let it look like this:

```kotlin
@ThreadLocal object DataService {

    private var dao: DataAccessObject? = null

    private val context = Dispatchers.Default

    fun injectDao(dao: DataAccessObject) {
        CoroutineScope(context).async {
            DataService.dao = dao
        }
    }

    suspend fun get(dataObjectType: TypeOfDataObject, id: String): DataObject? = withContext(context) {
        dao?.get(dataObjectType = dataObjectType, id = id)
    }

}
```

It is designed in such way that whenever and from whichever thread we call it - the code will run in background. To achieve that whenever we inject `dao` dependency, it is injected in background thread's copy of `DataService` object. Basically it works nice and all is triggered in background. But when we use `get` function for example and then try to modify the returned object - we have a mutability exception. So this code doesn't work:

```kotlin
suspend  fun test() {
    var object = get(TypeOfDataObject.someObject, id = "F702BCAF-DD63-4196-AA7B-E214248CAEB7")
    object.id = "whatever"
}
```

So what is the best way to deal with such situation? Imagine I just want to get an element from db, change some values and write it back, passing to an `update` function. How can I achieve that?

Does [Kotlin's Immutability](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/immutability.html) means that if this object is created in a background thread, it can be only updated in a background thread either?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Kotlin's Immutability means that if this object is created in a background thread, it can be only updated in a background thread either?

In summary, yes. If you want mutable state, the simple answer is only mutate it in the thread you've created it.

```kotlin
withContext(context) {
//whatever
}
```

Anything returned from the lambda passed to `withContext` will be frozen on return.

Now, I'd feel like I wasn't doing my job by not pointing out that you probably shouldn't be mutating data objects in the first place. However, you're not asking for that advice, so we'll leave that topic alone.

I would do something like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun get(dataObjectType: TypeOfDataObject, id: String, doStuff:(DataObject?)->DataObject?): DataObject? = withContext(context) {
    doStuff(dao?.get(dataObjectType = dataObjectType, id = id))
}
```

Then call it like this:

```kotlin
suspend  fun test() {
    var object = get(TypeOfDataObject.someObject, id = "F702BCAF-DD63-4196-AA7B-E214248CAEB7") { newObject ->
        newObject.id = "whatever"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for sharing this. What did you mean saying that I shouldn’t mutate data in that way? I will kindly ask for your advise if it’s still possible. Taking into account a pattern you have specified, I can’t clearly understand how can it be applied in my case to be honest. Imagine we have some user screen, where we’re showing an object fetched from the db. Then, based on some user activities we should modify this object and save it some time later. How should I make it if every time I fetch data from db it is frozen? Or suspending functions are not suitable in this case?

Comment: This isn't a Kotlin/Native specific thing. In general, data objects should be immutable. On the JVM, as a general best practice, data objects shouldn't be mutable. It's not a system requirement, but a generally accepted industry best practice. If you want mutable data in Kotlin/Native, then you'll need a way to detach your data objects from one thread and reattach them in another, but I highly recommend not doing that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Kevin, I'll research a bit more on this topic

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution suitable for me. I'll leave some notes below for time travelers possibly having this problem in future.

Basically I was overcomplicating the task I was trying to achieve. The most simple and suitable in this particular case way of making `suspend` functions work as I expected was just not to use them.

I prefer reactive programming style, thus there is nothing bad for me to use simple closures or lambdas as for the world of Kotlin. So it looks as simple as following:

```kotlin
@ThreadLocal object DataService {

    private var dao: DataAccessObject? = null

    private val scope = GlobalScope

    fun injectDao(dao: DataAccessObject) {
        scope.async {
            DataService.dao = dao
        }
    }

    fun get(dataObjectType: KNTypeOfDataObject, id: String, onComplete: (KNDataObject?) -> Unit) {
        scope.async {
            dao?.get(dataObjectType = dataObjectType, id = id, onComplete = onComplete)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks Kevin, for explaining these basics which helped me to find a simple and suitable way.

P.S. If any of time travelers will read this, please, leave a comment in what cases `suspend` functions are really suitable in case I use reactive programming style?